# How to add $value in HTML::script in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, frameworks

I have an array() in my controller and I am passing this array to footer.blade.php

```
$results['js'][] = "public/plugins/toastr-master/toastr.min.js";
$results['js'][] = "public/js/notifications.js";
return View::make('admin.logo_section.logo',$results);
```

I want to add value of above array into the HTML::script like this

```
@if(isset($js))
  @foreach($js as $js_value)
     {{ HTML::script('{{$js_value}}') }}    
  @endforeach
@endif
```

But it shows me some error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'
```

Please help me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the variable right away:

```
{{ HTML::script($js_value) }}
```

The problem you experienced with `'{{$js_value}}'` is probably due to the fact that Laravel parses your files looking for `{{}}` and compiles those into `echo` statements.

Comment: Thanks lukasgeiter :)